# Is there an equivalent to ModalPopup in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there an equivalent of ASP.NET's [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) in jQuery UI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure about ASP.net's implementation, but jQuery DEFINITELY has these types of popups.

Here's your basic popup: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/
Here's a list of plugins that are specifically modal popups: http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/modal

Comment: I need a popup modal that blocking the page and showing a progress icon while some process occuring.. is there a built-in plugin?

Answer (score 4):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ modal: true });
```

IMO, the jQuery UI popups behave much better than their ASP.Net equivalents (including when used with ASP.Net).

Comment: I need a popup modal that blocking the page and showing a progress icon while some process occuring.. is there a built-in plugin?

Comment: The jQuery UI toolkit also includes a progress bar: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/#default.  However, it will require connection with a server-side component (such as a web service returning JSON) if you are trying to report progress on a long-running action.

Comment: Actually i've made [bad experiences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662263/jquery-dialog-postback-but-updatepanel-doesnt-get-updated) with jQuery UI Dialog when used with ASP.Net-Ajax.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - I've posted a possible fix for you. I'm still looking for the perfect client/server dialog implementation; jQuery UI is not the ideal solution in many cases (and I'm not sure what IS that ideal solution).

Answer (score 1):

I've a great personal collection of top 15+ jquery modal plugins which really satisfies all our modal pop requirements using jQuery. Please feel free to comment about it.

http://itswadesh.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/. Here variety of Modal Pop ups are available. They all are really awesome. Choose and modify them as per your requirement.