# display the grid view like a drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is it possible to display a grid view table when a text or a button is clicked. When the user click on a text

```
view grid
```

then the gridview should just slide down the text view grid. Is there any ajax toolkit control to do that. I dont want it like a pop up want to display it in the same screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the collapsible Panel:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx

PS:  When you get really frustrated with the AJAX toolkit, you might want to look into jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: @Steve: Even if my opinion is unpopular, it's easier to get frustrated with ASP.NET Ajax + jQuery than with AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: ... example on frustrating jQuery UI issues with UpdatePanel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662263/jquery-dialog-postback-but-updatepanel-doesnt-get-updated